# 'unsafe-eval' MVC boilerplate

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, content-security-policy

I'm getting the error:

> vendor.js:328 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of the script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' localhost:* ajax.googleapis.com ajax.aspnetcdn.com".

I know I can solve this error by setting `UnsafeEval = true,`
but this is unsafe and open my site up to XSS vulnerabilities.

Therefore is there a way I can allow some scripts though, also forms when I use AJAX. maybe u guys can give me an example of how to use these methods I'm not quite sure how to do it.

```
new CspFormActionAttribute()
{
    // Allow forms to post back to example.com.
    // CustomSources = "*.example.com",
    // Allow forms to post back to the same domain.
    Self = true
});

new CspChildSrcAttribute()
{
    // Allow web workers or embed frames from example.com.
    // CustomSources = "*.example.com",
    // Allow web workers or embed frames from the same domain.
    Self = false
});

// connect-src - This directive restricts which URIs the protected resource can load using script interfaces
// (Ajax Calls and Web Sockets).
filters.Add(
    new CspConnectSrcAttribute()
    {

        // Allow Browser Link to work in debug mode only.
        CustomSources = string.Join(" ", "localhost:*", "ws://localhost:*"),

        // Allow AJAX and Web Sockets to example.com.
        // CustomSources = "*.example.com",

        // Allow all AJAX and Web Sockets calls from the same domain.
        Self = true
    });
```

Comment: Where is your Javascript?